# Seasons to be Cheerful

Tags: knowledge, wordplay, lateral-thinking

Happy hebdomidaire grapple fans!!

In an effort to get Stiv to have to think for more than two minutes - I've drawn a puzzle from the "
Spares" category, which is the equivalent of pulling that old unlabelled "rum" out of the drinks cabinet. In both cases a "Do Not Use" sticker lies intriguingly on the shelf.

Anyway, usual rules apply - each circle represents some(as yet) unknown category).  Each tile belongs to at least one category. Your task is to find out which tiles belong where and why?

AI

[image]

Answer (score 7):

> Set = plural seasons: Alice Springs, Palm Springs, Shelley Winters, Buffy Summers, Angel Falls

> Set = character in BTVS: Willow, Angel, Spike, Buffy

> Intersection = Buffy, Angel

@Stiv provided the last member in the intersection.

Comment: >!Everything on the right track but not quite

Comment: I think you also need rot13(Natry Snyyf - gur gnyyrfg jngresnyy va gur jbeyq - va gur vagrefrpgvba)

Answer (score 2):

This might be a stretch, but...

> [image]

Comment: I think you might be nearly there. You may like to note a couple of key words in the titles of [these](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palm_Springs,_California) [two](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffy_Summers) Wiki pages :)

Comment: >!yep getting there - well before I learn how to use spoilers!!!